# Is it possible to see how much logic an IP core uses?

Tags: digital-logic, fpga, vhdl, vivado

Is it possible to see how much logic an IP core uses in Vivado?
I just found out that one of my variable might create a giant mux. 
I want to know how much logic this mux uses, so I could document it somehow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When your program makes the synthesis of your VHDL, plenty of reports are generated. Normally you can see detailed logic resources usage per VHDL block, component and so on. This is the way I do it in Quartus.